# how to load environment variables when fork a sub shell in bash?

Tags: python, bash, fork

The next bash script was called in crontab.

I defined some environment variables for python in /etc/profile.d/python.sh.

$JOBCMD was some python script which will runing for long time, so I want to the script be called with fork.

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/profile.d/python.sh

JOBCMD=`/path/to/a_long_time_shell.py`

if [ -z "$variable" ]; then
    (
        . /etc/profile.d/python.sh
        $JOBCMD &
    )
fi

exit 0
```

The result is $JOBCMD can't get environment variables in /etc/profile.d/python.sh? How can I do to fix it?

Comment: How about calling $JOBCMD from python.sh? Or if that does not suit, pass the env variables as parameters to $JOBCMD.

Comment: If you don't use `export`, you're just defining shell variables, not environment variables.

Comment: all of environment variables were defined in /etc/profile.d/python.sh.

Comment: The sh script just failed when it was run by crontab.

Comment: Are you sure you want backquotes when you set the value of `JOBCMD`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can see of doing this is to export the variables in `python.sh`:

```
export a=123
export b=234
```

instead of

```
a=123
b=234
```

which I guess you're doing.

Or if you know which variables you want, you could export them before you call the script:

```
...
. /etc/profile.d/python.sh
export a
export b
$JOBCMD &
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export JOBCMD=`/path/to/a_long_time_shell.py`
```

Should make it available to all newly created process. Or, even better. You could use psutils to find the process by name and do something with it that way. Passing things into the environment is a weird way to do IPC.